# ORM find within object class declaration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, laravel, orm, mongoose

I've noticed a few ORM implementations where database search work happens as a static method on an object class like so in MongooseJS:

```
var myCar = new Car({ name: 'MyCar' });
Car.find({ name: /MyCar/ }, callback)
```

Rails and Laravel do something similar.  Does this seem strange to anyone else as a way of representing a Car?  To me, find() is more like factory method and should look something like

```
var myCar = new Car({ name: 'MyCar' });
CarFactory.find({ name: /MyCar/ }, callback)
```

or maybe even

```
var myCar = CarFactory.createCar({ name: 'MyCar' });
CarFactory.find({ name: /MyCar/ }, callback)
```

Even though find() is essentially a static method on the Car *class* (as opposed to the object itself), it still feels to me a bit too much like the car has knowledge of all the other cars.  Does this seem strange to anyone else, or am I overthinking this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have to split this answer up into two parts. The first part will be about *when to use factories* and the second one is a short 'behind the scenes' of an ORM. But before I start: this is heavily based on my own experiences. You should always decide on your own what suits best for your projects (in which cases it makes sense to use the factory pattern, in which not etc).

**When to use factories**

I often think about factories as a method to generate objects that have dependencies I do not have knowledge of at the time I'm creating them, or as a shorthand way to generate objects I need very often.

So for example, lets assume we have a factory method that finds all 'fast' cars.

```
class CarFactory {

    public static function getFastCars()
    {
        return Car::where('max_speed', '>', '180')->get();
    }

}
```

Now when we call this method like `$cars = CarFactory::getFastCars();`, I don't have to know about how fast a car must go in order to be *fast*. In your example however, you know about the name of the car, which is the only condition for the ORM to find your car(s). I think a factory would just make your code more complex here.

Another use case for factories could be to generate a specific *type* of a car. Lets imagine we are building a car rental service which has a feature where we can type a location we want to drive the car to and the service tells us which car is best for our journey. This is where factories come in handy:

```
/**
 * Car classes
 */
class Car {

    public function __toString()
    {
        return 'basic car';
    }

}

class SportsCar extends Car {

    public function __toString()
    {
        return 'sports car';
    }

}

class OffroadCar extends Car {

    public function __toString()
    {
        return 'off-road car';
    }

}

/**
 * The factory
 */
class CarFactory {

    public static function carForLocation($location)
    {
        $car = null;

        switch ($location)
        {
            case 'racetrack':
                $car = new SportsCar();
                break;
            case 'hills':
                $car = new OffroadCar();
                break;
            default:
                $car = new Car();
        }

        return $car;
    }

}


/**
 * Generating the car based on a location
 */
$car = CarFactory::carForLocation('racetrack');

echo "The type of car best for your journey is a {$car}.";

// Output: The type of car best for your journey is a sports car.
```

**About ORMs**

In my examples, the factories knew about all the cars. ORMs however, or *models* to be specific here, do not hold any information about any car (in their 'raw' state so to speak). Behind the scenes, when you call `Car.find({name: /MyCar/})`, the ORM will fetch the car information from the database over a query builder it depends on. Your car instance then holds that information in its properties.

This answer may be superficial in some parts (the ORM part especially), but I hope I could help you a little with this anyway.